# Convert DOCX to PDF from PHP

Tags: php, xhtml, tcpdf

Hi this is my first post here.

I have trouble in converting a docx file to pdf from PHP.
I am using PHPDOCX to convert the docx to xhtml and then pass the XHTML to TCPDF to generate the PDF. But I am losing a lot of formatting.

So I guess the above method is pointless.

Is there any free libraries that converts docx to pdf on the fly from PHP?

Comment: @rcro, Title maybe same but that post did not help me.

Comment: Well, then maybe you could tell us what was wrong with the other solution? What errors did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can go through the fallowing link,there we have phpdocx library.It may help you

www.phpdocx.com

Comment: please read my question properly. I have used PHPDOCX already and am not getting the results.

Comment: sorry,can you check another link, www.phplivedocx.org/2009/02/06/convert-doc-to-pdf-in-php/

Answer (score 1):

```
$phpLiveDocx = new Zend_Service_LiveDocx_MailMerge();
$phpLiveDocx->setUsername('username')
            ->setPassword('password');
$phpLiveDocx->setLocalTemplate('document.doc');
// necessary as of LiveDocx 1.2
$phpLiveDocx->assign('dummyFieldName', 'dummyFieldValue');
$phpLiveDocx->createDocument();
$document = $phpLiveDocx->retrieveDocument('pdf');
file_put_contents('document.pdf', $document);
unset($phpLiveDocx);
```

[Click here](http://www.phplivedocx.org/2009/02/06/convert-doc-to-pdf-in-php/) To details

[Link](http://www.phplivedocx.org/2009/02/06/convert-doc-to-pdf-in-php/)

Comment: I am not allowed to use ZEND framework. Any other alternatives available ? Thanks

Comment: its LiveDocx's (microsoft) online service you integrate in you core PHP.

checkout second link

http://www.phplivedocx.org/articles/using-livedocx-without-the-zend-framework/